# Update field based on calculation from previous rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to update the AvgScore record in my table based on the average of a field from several all rows for that person, for example, my table is like this:

```
rDate       | Name | Score | AvgScore
--------------------------------------------------
01/02/2018  | Dave | 12    |    
02/02/2018  | Bob  | 15    |    
02/02/2018  | Dave | 7     |    
03/03/2018  | Bob  | 18    |
```

So after I run the query it should look like this:

```
rDate       | Name | Score | AvgScore
--------------------------------------------------
01/02/2018  | Dave | 12    |   12 
02/02/2018  | Bob  | 15    |   15 
02/02/2018  | Dave | 7     |   9.5 
03/03/2018  | Bob  | 18    |   16.5
```

So for each record it will select all records where Name = 'personsName' prior to the current record and get the average score, then update the current record.

Currently Im using vb.net to do this row by row but it takes forever!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access SQL to get the average of two records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617646/ms-access-sql-to-get-the-average-of-two-records)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
update t
    set avgscore = (select avg(t2.score)
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.name = t.name and t2.rdate <= t.rdate
                   );
```